# Delete files in /var/cache to save space

Tags: debian

There is very little space left on my file system. I want to delete files in `/var/cache` to save disk space.  Are  there  some important files in the `/var/cache` which mustn't be deleted? If there are,please list all of them.
My system is Debian.

Comment: Did you already execute `apt-get clean` (as root)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I see, the only one folder in `/var/cache` that is big is `apt`. To safely delete apt's cache, run this command as `root`: `aptitude clean`. I'm not so sure about the others, they might be important, or might not. If you want to free up your disk space, you also want to use `bleachbit`.